# JOOQ Code generation could take into account composite unique constraints

Tags: jooq

Jooq - 3.13

We are using Jooq Codegen to generate using the `org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase` generation strategy.

When I have a table ex: Employee with a unique key constraint on say employee_number (this column is not a primary key) it generates a very useful method `fetchOneByEmployeeNumber` however I cannot say the same about composite keys.

If there is a composite unique key on (department_id, employee_number) then I'd like a method `findOneByDepartmentIdEmployeeNumber(Long departmentId, Long employeeNumber)`. Is this possible? (Obviously I can roll my own method for this purpose but we have quite a few of these constraints and auto generated methods will be very helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't being done right now for DAOs in jOOQ's code generator. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10597

As a workaround, you can extend jOOQ's `JavaGenerator::generateDaoClassFooter` method to generate your own, see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/

Comment: Thank you! This feature will be very useful!